# Why didn't my cheesecake bites come out right?

Tags: baking, batter

I used cream cheese, condensed milk, sugar and vanilla extract and some chopped oreos to make Oreo cheesecake bites. The crust was an actual Oreo. I baked this for an hour and when I took it out it wasn't sweet and it didn't come out like a cheese cake. It wasn't creamy like a cheesecake and it was a little bit hard on top. What did I do wrong? Please help

Comment: Did you use a recipe? If so, can you post it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that'd make a cheesecake not sweet (without some really obvious failure, like being burnt to charcoal) would be not enough sugar. Did your recipe maybe expect sweetened condensed milk, and you substituted regular condensed milk? (Well, presuming you know the recipe works—there are plenty of terrible recipes on the Internet).

Comment: The 'not creamy' can come from overcooking -- because the bites are much smaller than a full cheesecake, it's much more prone to overcooking.

Comment: I think Joe is right... An hour baking for something cupcake sized is a lot. If your recipe was for a full-sized cheesecake and you didn't cut the baking time considerably, these are really overbaked.

Comment: Please post the recipe and any changes you made, as currently it is a little bit too much guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate response would be that an hour for cheesecake bites seems to be way to long. The smaller your baked goods are, the faster they bake. I
I would lower the baking temperature slightly and reduce the time by at least half and test fro there.

If they are baked as a pan and cut, then the oven itself might be running hot, and you may want to check if it is accurate. Again try baking at a lower temp, cheesecake does well at lower temperatures. Could even try baking them in a water bath to keep them from getting to hot.

As to it not being sweet enough, the simple fix is to increase the sugar.